# How to link a url with the action bar icon/image ?

Tags: android, webview, android-actionbar

Hello I have an Android application ready. I would like to get help on ***how to link a url with the action bar icon?***

I want the action bar icon/image to load the main homepage into the web-view when the user clicks on it. For now, when the user clicks on it, nothing happens. So I want it to be linked with a homepage url that will help load the main homepage into the web-view.

Also, I would like to change the icon/image of the actionbar. For now, it automatically uses the icon for the application and I want to replace the actionbar icon with a different icon.

Thank you for ur help in advance. Any help/solutions to these two questions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a custom view for actionbar and provide it to the actionbar by using `actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);` and then handle the on click listener as you want.

Example:

```
 // Inflate your custom layout
final ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        R.layout.custom_actionbar,
        null);

// Set up your ActionBar
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(view);

ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ivIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

// custom_actionbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

### **UPDATE 2**

```
    // add to onCreate() / onCreateView()
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
                    return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: it works :) thanks! But getActionBar() is only for Honeycomb 3.0 and higher though. Right?

Comment: @fersarr The question was how to make the ActionBar icon clickable! however you can use getSupportActionBar() by extending ActionBarActivity to support older versions